# Difference between regular expressions for finding a word?

Tags: c#, regex

I just came across these 2 regular expressions while looking for parsing a sentence for words.

RegEx1: Used to split the words

> [^a-zA-Z]

RegEx2: From the previous splitted words, find words with this pattern.

> [a-zA-Z]

My question is what is both these regex looking for? An occurance of a word, ignore special character..?

Comment: Those are searching for letters, not words.  In the first example, the `^` denotes that the character sequence must **not** contain A to Z.

Comment: See [Regular Expression Character Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) and look for what the `^` (when applied to the start) means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good tool when dealing with regular expressions are online tools like 
http://regexhero.net/tester/

There can be slight differences between tools and your environment so fair warning.

If you use the tool you can see how [^a-zA-Z] matches non letters, while [a-zA-Z] matches letters.